# Android Calendar Provider exception on recurring events

Tags: android, android-contentprovider, android-calendar

I try to utilize the CalendarContract content provider: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/CalendarContract.Events.html

I only can't seem to find anything regarding exception on recurring events.
[I use the Instances URI to query](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/CalendarContract.Instances.html#CONTENT_URI).
I added an event (on calendar.google.com) and made it repeat every day. Now I changed one of the instances' time and the content provider gives me the exception correctly:

```
// Original event instance:
    eventID: 320
    instanceID: 651
    startdate: Wed Mar 13 09:30:00 CET 2013
    rrule: FREQ=WEEKLY;BYDAY=MO,TU,WE,TH,FR
    original_event_id: null
    exrule: null
    exdate: null

// Exception event instance:
    eventID: 333
    instanceID: 888
    startdate: Mon Mar 18 15:00:00 CET 2013
    rrule: null
    original_event_id: 320
    exrule: null
    exdate: null
```

As you can see above the original event has no `exrule` and `exdate` but the exception event is still shown correctly (not overlapping the original event instance)

Now here comes my question: I want to add an exception to a recurring event myself. But I don't know what fields I need to fill and how this works. Since the example above isn't helpful at all.

Answer (score -1):

I was a bit too hasty posting this question.
Inserting events to the `CalendarContract.Events.CONTENT_EXCEPTION_URI` will handle all of this ...

Comment: Is there any knowledge you can give on how to insert/update/delete using the `CalendarContract.Events.CONTENT_EXCEPTION_URI`?  I have been having an issue where whenever I delete a recurring event (using `Events.CONTENT_URI`), all my events disappear on the calendar (the `Instances` table is emptied but the `Events` table remains correct).  You can see my question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16392410/android-calendarcontract-deleting-a-recurring-event-causes-all-events-to-disapp

Comment: Plz tell me the way to insert/update/.... in 'CalendarContract.Events.CONTENT_EXCEPTION_URI'. I try many ways but unsccuessful, please my post at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16915993/make-exception-event-from-original-recurring-event

Comment: A bit more info would be nice :)