# Android CalendarContract, deleting a recurring event causes all events to disappear on calendar?

Tags: android, android-contentprovider, android-calendar, android-contentresolver, android-syncadapter

I have a sync adapter that handles syncing calendars and events.  I am able to delete normal events just fine.  But whenever I delete a recurring event, all the events on my calendar disappear.

One thing I noticed is that whenever I deleted a recurring event, the `Instances` table is emptied, which explains the events disappearing.  The `Events` table is as expected, with the recurring event row deleted from the table.

What is causing this?

I have tried deleting in the following ways:

```
resolver.delete(
    ContentUris.withAppendedId(Events.CONTENT_URI, id),
    null,
    null
);

resolver.delete(
    Events.CONTENT_URI,
    Events._ID + " = ?",
    new String[]{id}
);
```

And also as a `SyncAdapter`:

```
resolver.delete(
    Events.CONTENT_URI.buildUpon()
    .appendQueryParameter(CalendarContract.CALLER_IS_SYNCADAPTER, "true")
    .appendQueryParameter(Calendars.ACCOUNT_NAME, account.name)
    .appendQueryParameter(Calendars.ACCOUNT_TYPE, account.type)
    .build(),
    Events._ID + " = ?",
    new String[]{id}
);
```

All methods work correctly on non-recurring events, but all cause the `Instances` table to be emptied when deleting a recurring event.

**Update**

One thing I noticed is that the LogCat spits out the following error

- Application: `system_process`
- Tag: `BufferQueue`
- PID: `1187`
- TID: `1518`

`[com.android.calendar/com.android.calendar.AllInOneActivity] BufferQueue:drainQueueLocked: timeout waiting on consumer!`

Comment: How did you solve this problem? Is Google aware of this?

Comment: @ChristopherMasser Hi Christopher, I did solve the problem.  Sorry for the late response.  See my solution in the answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turned out to be an error on my part.  When my `SyncAdapter` was adding calendars to the database, I was not properly setting the field `SYNC_EVENTS` (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/CalendarContract.CalendarColumns.html#SYNC_EVENTS).  Specifically, this field should be set to `1`.

It was difficult to know that this was the issue because I was still able to technically "sync" (push events to the server and pull events from the server), but I was just running into the issue my events disappearing.

I hope this helps someone else too.